# So many Anagrams!

Tags: word, anagram

For this puzzle, you have to find two words that are anagrams of each other to fit into the "____". For example, you might place *earth* and *heart*.

---

> 1. After we _____ for many hours we were very ________.
> 2. After Jane played a sour _____ on the piano, the whole ____ was ruined.
> 3. Mark placed his ______ in the deep, blue ______.
> 4. Suzy bought 40 _____ of shoes in _____.
> 5. While watching John grab his hot ____ of oats, Steve recommended that he should ____ on it to cool it down.
> 6. While driving for the first time, Luke had to remember not to ____ into the _______ around the side of the road.
> 7. Jimmy complained that the _____ in his smoothie was too sour, and the ______ was too sweet.
> 8. After picking up a prickly red ____, Tasha's hand was _____.
> 9. After proof-reading an article about healthy ______, Tom realized that he needed to make some serious ______.
> 10. You wash your hands in the _____ to clean your ______.
> 11. Joan likes to ______ when she has a hot cup of _______.

Comment: I think we're all stuck on 6 and 9

Comment: I think there's a much more plausible answer to 6 than the one two people have given here. It's 5 letters rather than 4.

Comment: I got it!! (number 6)

Comment: aiyaa 28 views only? And already at top of HNQ list

Comment: Is #3 supposed to be "**in** the deep, blue" instead of "is"?  And for #10, I assume "to clean **your**"?

Comment: Please make more of these "anagram" puzzles! I was not able to solve your [most recent riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67919/i-have-an-extravagant-sense-of-humour), but I was for this one. This was great :)

Comment: Sure I would be glad to @user477343, these happen to be my favorite puzzles to make. In the mean time check out this other similar puzzle https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64568/so-many-homophones :D

Comment: Actually, yeah, I have time. I thought I needed to go to sleep, but I didn't. Apparently my watched stopped working last night, hahahah. On it, now :))

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## FINAL ANSWER:

1:

> After we **tried** for many hours we were very **tired**.

2:

> After Jane played a sour **note** on the piano, the whole **tone** was ruined.

3:

> Mark placed his **canoe** is the deep, blue **ocean**.

4:

> Suzy bought 40 **pairs** of shoes in **Paris**.

5:

> While watching John grab his hot **bowl** of oats, Steve recommended that he should **blow** on it to cool it down.

6:

> While driving for the first time, Luke had to remember not to **steer** into the **trees** around the side of the road. (Credit to WELZ)

7:

> Jimmy complained that the **lemon** in his smoothie was too sour, and the **melon** was too sweet.

8:

> After picking up a prickly red **rose**, Tasha's hand was **sore**.

9:

> After proof-reading an article about healthy **diets**, Tom realized that he needed to make some serious **edits**.

10:

> You wash your hands in the **sink** to clean your **skin**.

11:

> Joan likes to **eat** when she has a hot cup of **tea**.

Comment: I haven't included your hint though, why the first three words matter...

Comment: Which basically means I haven't figure it out yet...

Comment: I think he was referencing "After proof-reading" and the word was **Edit**.

Answer (score 7):

PARTIAL

1. > After we **tried** for many hours we were very **tired**.
2. > After Jane played a sour **note** on the piano, the whole **tone** was ruined.
3. > Mark placed his **canoe** is the deep, blue **ocean**.
4. > Suzy bought 40 **pairs** of shoes in **paris**.
5. > While watching John grab his hot **bowl** of oats, Steve recommended that he should **blow** on it to cool it down.
6. > While driving for the first time, Luke had to remember not to skid into the disk around the side of the road.
7. > Jimmy complained that the **lemon** in his smoothie was too sour, and the **melon** was too sweet.
8. > After picking up a prickly red **rose**, Tasha's hand was **sore**.
9. > After proof-reading an article about healthy **diets**, Tom realized that he needed to make some serious **edits**.
10. > You wash your hands in the **sink** to clean you **skin**.
11. > Joan likes to **eat** when she has a hot cup of **tea**.

Comment: Exactly the same as mine :P

Comment: Missing 6 and 9

Comment: Nope apparently 6 isn't right.

Answer (score 6):

FINAL ANSWER

1:

> After we **tried** for many hours we were very **tired**.

2:

> After Jane played a sour **note** on the piano, the whole **tone** was ruined.

3:

> Mark placed his **canoe** is the deep, blue **ocean**.

4:

> Suzy bought 40 **pairs** of shoes in **Paris**.

5:

> While watching John grab his hot **bowl** of oats, Steve recommended that he should **blow** on it to cool it down.

6:

> While driving for the first time, Luke had to remember not to **steer** into the **trees** around the side of the road. (Credit to WELZ)

7:

> Jimmy complained that the **lemon** in his smoothie was too sour, and the **melon** was too sweet.

8:

> After picking up a prickly red **rose**, Tasha's hand was **sore**.

9:

> After proof-reading an article about healthy **diets**, Tom realized that he needed to make some serious **edits**.

10:

> You wash your hands in the **sink** to clean your **skin**.

11:

> Joan likes to **eat** when she has a hot cup of **tea**.

Comment: uhhh, hide this?

Comment: Would be better if you didn't hide the numbers so we know which ones you've answered.

Comment: I didn't make the edit, only approved it - I believe @WELZ suggested it :)

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie I put a new 6 in my answer.

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie this is the first time I have 10 messages in my inbox

Answer (score 6):

Partial:

Nobody else got yet:

It's:

> Steer into the Trees!!!

6:

> Skid into the **KIDS** around the road

or

> Slide into the Delis around the road.

---

5:

> While watching John grab his hot **BOWL** of oats, Steve recommended that he should **BLOW** on it to cool it down

10:

> You wash your hands in the **SINK** to clean you **SKIN**.

11:

> Joan likes to **EAT** when she has a hot cup of **TEA**.

Comment: Damn, that new 6 answer is dark...

Comment: Uh I highly think your #6-2 is worse than your #6-1...

Comment: lmao but nice try though

Comment: Ooh, i think you nailed it!

Comment: finallyyyy lolol

Comment: wait @quantumtwinkie you want me to make a community wiki answer?

Comment: YES WELZ you got it!!!

Comment: Skid into the kids! $(+1)$ when my vote limit is over :))

Answer (score 5):

Partial:

1.

> After we *tried* for many hours we were very *tired*.

2.

> After Jane played a sour *note* on the piano, the whole *tone* was ruined.

4.

> Suzy bought 40 *pairs* of shoes in *paris*.

5.

> While watching John grab his hot *bowl* of oats, Steve recommended that he should *blow* on it to cool it down.

6.

> While driving for the first time, Luke had to remember not to ____ into the _______ around the side of the road.

7.

> Jimmy complained that the *lemon* in his smoothie was too sour, and the *melon* was too sweet.

8.

> After picking up a prickly red *rose*, Tasha's hand was *sore*.

9.

> After proof-reading an article about healthy ______, Tom realized that he needed to make some serious ______.

10.

> You wash your hands in the *sink* to clean your *skin*. (Credits to NL628)

11.

> Joan likes to *eat* when she has a hot cup of *tea*.

Comment: Wait @QuantumTwinkie the number of dashes doesn't matter?

Comment: @NL628 some of the dash pairs in a single question does not match each others' lengths, so i assumed they don't matter

Answer (score 5):

Partial answer.

6.

> Steer / Trees

8.

> Rose / Sore

9.

> Diets / Edits

10.

> Sink / Skin

11.

> eat / tea

Comment: Yes!! 9 is correct! :D

Answer (score 4):

1

> After we **medicated** for many hours we were very **decimated**.

2

> After Jane played a sour **thing** on the piano, the whole **night** was ruined.

3

> Mark placed his **master** in the deep, blue **stream**.

4

> Suzy bought 40 **dollars worth** of shoes in **Harlots' World**.

5

> While watching John grab his hot **sips** of oats, Steve recommended that he should **piss** on it to cool it down.

6

> While driving for the first time, Luke had to remember not to **skid** into the **kids** around the side of the road.

7

> Jimmy complained that the **grapefruit** in his smoothie was too sour, and the **grape (fruit)** was too sweet.

8

> After picking up a prickly red **insect**, Tasha's hand was **nicest**.

9

> After proof-reading an article about healthy **conservation**, Tom realized that he needed to make some serious **conversation**.

10

> You wash your hands in the **Hessians** to clean your **ashiness**.

11

> Joan likes to **throb** when she has a hot cup of **broth**.

Comment: A better answer for #10 is probably "You wash your hands in the **spring water** to clean your **tiger prawns**." (I am assuming that you are holding tiger prawns in your hands?)

Comment: I like the creativity +1 but none of them are correct.

Answer (score 1):

> Suzy bought 40 pairs of shoes in paris.

.

> While watching John grab his hot bowl of oats, Steve recommended that he should blow on it to cool it down.

.

> While driving for the first time, Luke had to remember not to lean into the lane around the side of the road.

.

> Jimmy complained that the lemon in his smoothie was too sour, and the melon was too sweet.