# How can the baby live?

Tags: lateral-thinking, situation

One day, while in a twenty-story building, Mary was holding her 2 month old baby. As Mary was playing with the baby, she accidentally dropped it out the window. The baby, though, survived. How?

(**The baby was wearing normal clothes, not anything special to protect it from this sort of thing.**)

Comment: Lol possibly too broad? Maybe edit it?

Comment: I just added the lateral thinking tag. I want to see what types of answers people will come up with.

Comment: Oh no! Not the dreaded lateral thinking tag! jk :P

Comment: I just wrote a very very lateral thinking answer for you  :P

Comment: Yay kraby15 just hit the 1000 mark :D

Comment: This is a time for celebration. :P

Comment: @kraby15 We specifically *do not want* puzzles open ended enough that the idea of "I want to see what types of answers people will come up with" enters into it. We even have a close reason for: "This question may invite speculative answers, as the question is not fully defined. The validity of some answers may be based upon opinion. Good questions for this site have a limited number of objectively correct answers. See also: [Why are questions off-topic if they invite answers which are not demonstrably correct, or are otherwise speculative?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1254)"

Comment: Note to answerers: If you see a question that is sufficiently undefined that, even though you can pretty quickly guess what the intended answer is, you can readily come up with other, equally Not Wrong solutions to the puzzle as written, *please* restrain your urge to indulge in posting "clever", "funny" or "unique" solutions.  IF you do that, it should be specifically to demonstrate how the puzzle is too broad, and *you should remove the obviously not intended "solutions" afterward* - your aim was to instruct, not to leave permanent commentary on the puzzle (nor to gain rep from doing so).

Comment: Note to the community: "brain teasers" riddles are almost never a good fit for our objective of creating a collection of high quality puzzles and Q&A about puzzles. They almost invariably suffer from being too broad, as well as being so well known to so many people that they're not interesting - answering them is not so much "solving" them as it is seeing who can type the answer first. Ideally, people wouldn't post them; if they did, people wouldn't answer them; and if such questions and answers did appear, the community would vote to keep them off the site, with downvotes, VTCs, and VTDs.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Perhaps:

> Mary was on the ground floor of the 20-story building.

Comment: You were first.

Comment: By 15 whole seconds, yep! :D

Comment: Will you accept puzzledPig's answer? It's kind of scary realizing that my answer is first even though I know for a fact it's wrong...

Answer (score 14):

The baby was a

> Baby cat and cat's always land on their feet :P

Comment: Creative answer, but not the one i was looking for. lol

Comment: I know lol I was just posting something different XD

Comment: The only problem is that a two-month old kitten would most likely not survive a fall like that.

Comment: Lol true :P letsee...robotic kitten?

Comment: Actually cats start at a very young age, and may have perfected it by 2 months old. Cats will always land on their feet, assuming they're dropped from at least a few feet off the ground.

Comment: @Tas Landing on their feet is one thing, Surviving a feet-first fall of several stories is a different stor(e)y ;-)

Comment: It would possibly not work for kittens, but the severity of fall *is* tied to creature's weight (as well as the shape it has while falling - think flying squirrels). I think a baby spider would  survive ok.

Comment: "You can drop a mouse down a thousand-yard mine shaft and, on arriving at the bottom, it gets a slight shock and walks away. A rat is killed, a man is broken, a horse splashes." -- J B S Haldane, from his classic essay "On being the right size". Yes, a baby spider would be absolutely fine.

Answer (score 11):

What about

> The baby is a doll, Mary is a little kid (or just a little different)

Why:

> You used the word It every time you refer to **it** (multiple times), not he/him/her/she/

Comment: interesting theory...

Comment: (The baby was wearing normal clothes, not anything special to protect it from this sort of thing.)...when you take this too literally and you assume the baby does not have skin but rather plastic... LOL

Answer (score 9):

What about

> There is a balcony just below the window, perhaps even with a padded chair...

Answer (score 8):

> The building is twenty stories but Mary lives on the first floor

Comment: @puzzledPig posted the same answer before you :P

Comment: @NL628 I see that now. Some of these riddles have 10 people get the answer instantly and it's a battle of typing it the fastest.

Comment: Yep :P check this one out: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64049/so-many-anagrams

Answer (score 7):

> Even in tall buildings, not all windows are necessarily external windows (think glazing between a kitchen and breakfast room) ... and even among external windows, not all of them overlook a sheer drop... (think living room to balcony).
> *Update* also not all windows are glazed house  windows are they? (think of a child's playhouse / "wendy-house" with fabric walls and a lightweight frame, to play in, and the parent holding the child out of its "window" to make him/her giggle)
> After all, you only said "the" window but never said what kind of window or where it overlooked......

Answer (score 6):

Oh, this one's obvious.

> A tornado happened to be drifting by at the time, but it wasn't strong enough to carry the baby away, just strong enough to slow and soften the baby's landing. Obviously.

Comment: That''s some next level lateral thinking here.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe

> Mary was holding a baby butterfly. Butterflies learn how to fly pretty quickly, and thus, the butterfly would survive.

Comment: hmm...  interesting.

Comment: Not an entomologist, but... can butterflies even be babies? I was under the impression that butterfly was the "adult" stage.

Comment: How a butterfly were wearing normal clothes?

Comment: @HolaSoyEduFelizNavidad Well, normal for a butterfly.

Answer (score 3):

You think that their head would be split!

> Good luck was with them that morning - they fell in a barrel of [shaving cream](https://youtu.be/G8ffkDf0ol4?t=57s)

Answer (score 3):

> Because she was holding the baby standing on the ground floor.

Comment: Hello and welcome to PSE. Please hide your answers in spoilers.

Answer (score 3):

> The baby fall inwards and not outwards of the window.

Comment: Welcome to PSE. Please hide your answers in spoilers.

Answer (score 3):

> There was a window cleaner at the 19<sup>th</sup> storey, who caught the baby.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is lateral thinking...

> The world they are in is made of *jelly*. So the roads are made of jelly and the baby just bounced off with no injuries...