# So Many Homophones?

Tags: word

A twist on my previous puzzle [So many anagrams](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64049/so-many-anagrams). Instead of finding anagrams for the blanks you have to find two homophones/homographs(bat-bat, and doe-dough) that fit into the provided blanks. *Note: The number of blanks does not mean the number of letters and there will be a different set of hompphones for each numbered sentence*

---

> 1. Donny started to _____ up when he saw that there was a _____ in his leather seats.
> 2. Mike took his _____ on a date to the ______.
> 3. After an _____ course meal, Joe figured that he ______ enough!
> 4. He was wishing that his ______ would ______, because he wanted to start playing soccer again.
> 5. Because the ________ was flat, it was a perfect spot to land their _______.
> 6. After bathing their pet ______ the drain was full of ______.
> 7. They _____ed  the couch through the ____.
> 8. Talking ______ is not _________.
> 9. They went through the _____ _____ and got lost while trying to get out.
> 10. To be more efficient in landscaping our yard we worked in ____s. First we _____d the ____ tree so it would not look so bushy, then we cut the grass.
> 11. Ally only went to the shoe-stores that had a wide variety of  _______, and after she was done shopping,  she knew  _______ she was going to ______  all the shoes.
> 12. _____ days ago, I wanted to do a trick shot ____ my turn, so I swung as had as I could but the ball was about to hit my coach, so I screamed _____!

Comment: Are you sure these are all homophones?  It looks like #1 may be a homograph (same spelling, different sound and meaning) instead.  Or I may be thinking of the wrong answer.

Comment: Hmmm remember what happened last time you did "So many anagrams?" It seems like things have calmed down a bit...lol

Comment: Oh. I just spent a good ten minutes trying, and utterly failing, to solve this, until I finally gave up in exasperation and looked at the accepted answer. Turns out it was the instructions that were misleading—you don’t have to find _two_ homophones/homographs (one pair), but _twenty-seven_ (twelve sets of two or three each, one set per sentence). I was desperately trying to find one single pair of homophones or homographs that would fit all twelve sentences. :-/

Comment: Also, one of the three in #12 is neither a homophone nor a homograph with the others. It’s both spelt and pronounced differently (in this context) than the other two.

Comment: I sorry I will edit  saying that there will be a different homophone for each number and which one out of 12 is different 1 2 or 3?

Comment: #3 should be "eight" and "had eaten"

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie the middle one is pronounced differently from the first and third one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1:

> tear/ tear (this one is the homograph, as @Pugmonkey pointed out)

2: credit to @Pugmonkey, go upvote [their answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/64571/38170)!

> bae/ bay

3:

> eight/ ate

4:

> heel/ heal

5:

> plain/ plane

6:

> hare/ hair

7:

> haul/ hall

8:

> aloud/ allowed

9:

> maize/ maze

10:

> pair/ pare/ pear

11: credit to @Reinier, go upvote [their answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/64570/38170)!

> ware/ where/ wear

12:

> four/ for/ fore

Comment: I think I got 2 (see my answer).  Feel free to add it to your list.

Comment: 7 is possibly [ROT13](http://www.webutils.pl/index.php?idx=rot&mode=rot13&dec=DECODE&data=yvsg+%2F+yvsg)

Comment: While I think 3 is correct, there is a slight problem with the article preceding the first word.

Comment: @Bass yeah, I noticed that, but figured QuantumTwinkie might have felt that "an" or "a(n)" was too much of a hint

Answer (score 9):

1. Donny started to _____ up when he saw that there was a _____ in his leather seats.

> Tear - tear

2. Mike took his _____ on a date to the ______.

> Bae - bay

3. After a _____ course meal, Joe figured that he ______ enough!

> eight - ate

4. He was wishing that his ______ would ______, because he wanted to start playing soccer again.

> heel - heal

5. Because the ________ was flat, it was a perfect spot to land their _______.

> plain - plane

6. After bathing their pet ______ the drain was full of ______.

> hare - hair

7. They _____ed the couch through the ____.

> ???

8. Talking ______ is not _________.

> ???

9. They went through the _____ _____ and got lost while trying to get out.

> maize - maze

10. To be more efficient in landscaping our yard we worked in ____s. First we _____d the ____ tree so so it would not look so bushy, then we cut the grass.

> ???

11. Ally only went to the shoe-stores that had a wide variety of _______, and after she was done shopping, she knew _______ she was going to ______ all the shoes.

> ???

12. _____ days ago, I wanted to do a trick shot ____ my turn, so I swung as had as I could but the ball was about to hit my coach, so I screamed _____!

> four - for - fore

Comment: Ooh, that's a nice answer for #2!  My answer has a few of the ones you're missing, though I know sometimes it's more fun to not peek :)

Comment: Yeah, you were fast (and good). There were no answers when I started writing, but you had it almost finished before I posted.  Good job!

Answer (score 8):

I found another one:

11:

> ware / where / wear

Answer (score 1):

I found another one:

9. > They went through the $\underline{sweet}$ $\underline{suite}$ and got lost while trying to get out.

And another one, but a little relaxed.

7. > They $\underline{miss}$ed the couch through the $\underline{mist}$.

And another that although makes sense, seems a bit silly.

6. > After bathing their pet $\underline{moose}$ the drain was full of $\underline{mousse}$.

If I could add apostrophes or one other word, I would include for $8$,

> *"Talking* ***write***${}$*" is not* ***right***.

> A talking **chilli** is not **chilly**.

Comment: Very, clever I didn't think of those.