# I have an extravagant sense of humour

Tags: riddle, wordplay

Here is my latest riddle, take a crack at it if you dare!

> Need to reinforce your brain?
>
> Need help going with the flow?
>
> Then I am exceptional for the job!
>
> I am not a coward, but my family is.
>
> I have an extravagant sense of humour,
>
> I can be within precision,  masters, and drastic-ness,
>
> Most people see me and think, “It’s what is on the inside that counts!”
>
> Yet leave out an important part of me!
>
> Well, I am not gonna exaggerate,
>
> But people believe I am an important part of a holiday, yet I am not.
>
> Still people may have me everyday,
>
> Since the beginning of time?

**Hint 1**

> Maybe synonyms?

**Hint 2**

> I am telling the truth I do not EXAGGERATE!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is

> An egg

Need to reinforce your brain?

> "Eggs are a good source of several nutrients tied to brain health, including vitamins B6 and B12, folate and choline." [source](https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/11-brain-foods)

Need help going with the flow?

> (From OP) Eggs contain good cholesterol which helps with blood flow

Then I am exceptional for the job!

> If you say "exceptional" out loud it kind of sounds like "egg-ceptional"

I am not a coward, but my family is.

> They're all chicken

I have an extravagant sense of humour,

> "*Eggs*travagant"

I can be within precision, masters, and drastic-ness,

> Precision = Exact = *Eggs*act
>  Masters = Experts = *Eggs*perts
>  Drastic = Extreme = *Eggs*treme

Most people see me and think, “It’s what is on the inside that counts!”

> The egg contains a baby chick. Possibly a reference to "Don't count your chicks before they hatch!"

Yet leave out an important part of me!

> The shell protects the baby chick. Also (from OP), many people don't like to eat the yolk

Well, I am not gonna exaggerate,

> "*Eggs*aggerate"

But people believe I am an important part of a holiday, yet I am not.

> Colored eggs are common around Easter, but Easter is actually a Christian holiday celebrating the resurrection of Jesus and has nothing to do with eggs.

Still people may have me everyday,

> Some people eat eggs for breakfast every day.

Since the beginning of time?

> A reference to the classic question, "Which came first, the chicken or the egg?"

Comment: Spot on! You just need to add "the go with the flow" part to be It is good cholesterol for your arteries. And, the part "yet leave out an important part of me" is when people don't each the yolks. Great job :D

Comment: I should have trusted my instincts, but I didn't, and it turns out that they were right all along.... $(+1)$

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer might be

> Stress

Need to reinforce your brain?

> To stress means to give particular emphasis or importance to something. Stressing an idea reinforces it in your mind.

Need help going with the flow?

> [Flow stress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_stress) is the instantaneous value of stress required to continue plasticly deforming a material.

Then I am exceptional for the job!

> [Occupational Stress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occupational_stress) is stress related to one's job. Also notice the exclamation mark and the word *exceptional* which provide a stress to the sentiment.

I am not a coward, but my family is.

> Not sure about this one but I think it's referring to a hypothesized family of innate emotions (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear)), including acute stress reaction, anxiety, fright and fear.

I have an extravagant sense of humour,

> One definition of humour is just a mood or state of mind and a stress is a state of mental or emotional strain or tension, so, in that way, stress is a sense of humour. The word extravagant here again adds stress to the notion.

I can be within precision, masters, and drastic-ness,

> This is to do with the stress on syllables in a word i.e, pre*cis*ion, *ma*sters, *dra*stic-*ness*. Acquiring precision or mastery could also involve quite a lot of stress as would a drastic activity.

Most people see me and think, “It’s what is on the inside that counts!”

> In mechanics, stress is a physical quantity that expresses the internal forces that neighbouring particles of a continuous material exert on each other.

Yet leave out an important part of me!

> Perhaps the external metaphorical stress (forces) experienced?

Well, I am not gonna exaggerate,

> Stressing and exaggerating are closely related, but very different, ideas (almost antonyms).

But people believe I am an important part of a holiday, yet I am not.

> When we think of the build-up to a holiday, such as Christmas, that could involve a lot of stress in preparation. In the end, holidays are supposed to be stress-free.

Still people may have me everyday,

> Yes, a lot of people have stress in their everyday life.

Since the beginning of time?

> Stress is synonymous with pressure or tension so you could say the Big Bang resulted from an extraordinary amount of stress at a single point.

Hint 2

> Notice the stress on the word *exaggerate* and repetition of an idea which is another stress.

Comment: Great answer, but incorrect :D +1