# Many more Anagrams!

Tags: word, anagram

Here I have [yet another](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64049/so-many-anagrams) anagram puzzle to be solved. The rules are you have to find the anagram pair, that can be placed in the "_____", and the number of "__" spaces does not matter. Enjoy!

> 1. Every time May goes on her _____, it makes her feel like she has _____ and that she is flying.
> 2. Whenever John asks too many _____s, his father says, "____ ____"
> 3. Jim does not like driving downtown because there are so many ____s where he has to ____.
> 4. Moe went into his Grandfather's _____, to read, but everything in there was very ______.
> 5. The more _____ that Noah completed during the marathon the wider he _____d.
> 6. Joe had a great a____ for cleaning the a____.
> 7. When the last few contestants were still standing, Mark look up to the competition and said "Then ____ were ____".
> 8. Mary feels like all of the water she drank is _____d, through all of her _____.
> 9. The health inspectors believe that the ____ was the _____ of the food poisoning.
> 10. It is very easy to _____ someone else, when the room is ____.
> 11. ______ dislike having _______ taking the tests.

EDIT, I removed #12 due to confusion and error.

Comment: @user477343, here is another one of those anagram puzzles you requested here: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64049/so-many-anagrams#comment204470_64049 :D

Comment: 2: "to" to "too"?

Comment: Are you sure #12 is correct? (I ask because an almost-answer jumps out at me but the third space doesn't quite match the first two.) [EDITED to add:] Or maybe the first space; the second could be either of two things, one of which makes the first work and the other of which makes the third work.

Comment: Is 12 valid? Or is it a mistake? (You were unclear on whether the answer was something else, or if that was your intended answer but it is incorrect)

Comment: Maybe you should just remove it? I mean, either that, or you remove the third blank and only use the first two. Don't ask me! :|

Comment: The only anagram pairs which both begin with A in SOWPODS are anarchies/anarchise, analogies/analogise, anopias/anopsia, alchemies/alchemise, anthologies/anthologise, apologies/apologise, agonies/agonise, aeronomists/astronomies/astronomise, autotomies/autotomise; so number 6 must be using a pretty obscure word.

Comment: @PeterTaylor In line with the common usage nature of the other words, I believe that the first blank in #6 shouldn't start with an 'a' (and that this is a typo in the question).

Comment: In no 6, if both anagrams had the additional 'a' , then  that 'a' wouldn't be needed in the type. Something's awry.

Comment: Hahah, you have inspired me to make my own anagram puzzle! I will credit you for that. Making one now :D

Comment: I'll be sure to check it out :D @user477343

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Everything put together:

1 (Zimzonze) :

> Every time May goes on her SWING, it makes her feel like she has WINGS and that she is flying.

2 (Gareth McCaughan):

> Whenever John asks too many QUESTIONs, his father says, "QUIET SON".

3 (Florian Bourse):

> Jim does not like driving downtown because there are so many SPOTs where he has to STOP.

4 (Gareth McCaughan):

> Moe went into his Grandfather's STUDY, to read, but everything in there was very DUSTY.

5 (Riley):

> The more MILES that Noah completed during the marathon the wider he SMILEd.

6 (Ian MacDonald):

> Joe had a great TACIT for cleaning the ATTIC.

7 (Riley):

> When the last few contestants were still standing, Mark look up to the competition and said "Then THERE were THREE".

8 (hagfy):

> Mary feels like all of the water she drank is WASTEd, through all of her SWEAT.

9 (Riley):

> The health inspectors believe that the SAUCE was the CAUSE of the food poisoning.

10 (Matt):

> It is very easy to LISTEN (to) someone else, when the room is SILENT.

11 (Riley):

> TEACHERS dislike having CHEATERS taking the tests.

Comment: or Number 3 could be rot13("fcbgf" naq "fgbc")

Comment: #3 is rot13(fcbg), #10 is rot13(yvfgra) ?

Comment: Could you please give credit for the answers you didn't find first? As it stands, this post makes it sound like you found them all first.

Comment: Ok, I will :D :D

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie If the second one for #6 is ADIC, the first one must either be ADCI, ACDI, AICD, or AIDC, but none of them make sense

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie but you said ACID was wrong

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie Now is it right?

Comment: Great job :) I will accept your answer later because you have them all.

Comment: Since your answer is really just a combination of all the other answers, I think this should be a community wiki answer instead.

Comment: I think Riley is right, so if you guys make one I will accept it @PotatoLatte :)

Comment: I think you mean a great *TACTIC, not a great TACIT. (6)

Comment: Yes... [tacit](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tacit) is an adjective; not something someone can "have". Also, it doesn't start with *a*, as was implied by the puzzle.

Comment: @IanMacDonald I know, but it was the only anagram of ATTIC, and it was somehow right...

Comment: I was going to use something very similar to #11 in my anagram puzzle, but decided to be a little bit more original instead :)

Answer (score 7):

I got a few:

1

> SWING, WINGS

3

> POST, STOP (not confident on this one)

7

> THERE, THREE

9

> COURSE, SOURCE

10

> RESCUED, SECURED, REDUCE[S] ('would' is unnecessary?)

Comment: I barely beat you on #7 :)

Comment: @Riley Yup, so sad :/

Answer (score 7):

8 is:

> Mary feels like all of the water she drank is **WASTE**d, through all of her **SWEAT**.

Trollish guess for 6:

> Joe had a great **ART** for cleaning the **ART**

Comment: Yep that is correct :D

Comment: How can ART be an anagram of ART?

Comment: @Tim, that's why it's trollish. But it's the only suggestion I've seen in this thread which doesn't rely on OP having made *two* mistakes in the same subquestion. However, looking at OP's comments on another answer, it seems that they did make two mistakes on #6.

Comment: @PeterTaylor - yet OP says it's correct? I rarely downvote, but with many mistakes, and words that aren't anagrams due to extra letters needed, this is one occasion. I generally leave reasons for downvoting, unlike most...  Dammit - the system won't let me!!

Comment: @Tim Only 8 was correct.  I added the ART line after that.  Sorry for the timeline confusion.

Comment: @Tim, OP's comment on PotatoLatte's answer says that it was meant to be TACTIC and ATTIC, but (1) they aren't anagrams and (2) TACTIC doesn't begin with A. I've already downvoted the question (and upvoted this answer, because I admire the way hagfy cut the Gordian knot of an impossible question).

Answer (score 7):

My personal version for 6:

> Joe had a great **tool** for cleaning the **loot**.

Answer (score 6):

I've found a few.

5.

> MILES, SMILE

7.

> THERE, THREE

9.

> SAUCE, CAUSE

11.

> TEACHERS, CHEATERS

Comment: Yep those are correct :D

Answer (score 6):

Since some others are posting partial answers, here are mine.

3 Whenever John asks too many _____s, his father says, "____ ____"

> QUESTION, QUIET SON

4 Moe went into his Grandfather's _____, to read, but everything in there was very ______.

> STUDY, DUSTY

7 When the last few contestants were still standing, Mark look up to the competition and said "Then ____ were ____".

> THERE, THREE

And some that are wrong if they are right (if you see what I mean); I bet this just indicates that my "solutions" are not the intended ones, but you never know...

3 Jim does not like driving downtown because there are so many ____s where he has to ____.

> STREET, STEER [second is missing a T]

[EDITED to remove a proposal for the now-removed #12]

Comment: The only incorrect one is "Steer" and "Street", other the rest are right :D

Answer (score 6):

6:

> Joe had a great TIP for cleaning the PIT.

Answer (score 5):

How about this for 6?

> TALENT, LATTEN

Or how about this?

> SKILL, KILLS

Comment: Wow, that is an awesome answer, but it is not the intended answer :D

Comment: New second guess is not correct, :) Keep up the good searching!

Answer (score 4):

I think 10 would be

> LISTEN, SILENT

though it works better if there is a "to" after the first blank.

Comment: Perhaps ENLIST, SILENT?

Comment: @matt, you are correct :D

Answer (score 4):

#6, taking notice of the leading **a** (and misspelling through phonetics):

> Joe had a great **acid** for cleaning the **adic**. (*attic*)

Comment: VERY, VERY close, the last correct word is right. Just find a anagram for it (not acid or adic) :D

Comment: Is it Cadi or Caid?

Comment: Actually, doesn't it have to be ADCI or ACDI?

Comment: WHAT ODES THAT EVEN MEAN